# How can I read a text inside of a txt file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

my question is might be confusing. I have a bash script, I want this bash script to do a create a password by mkpasswd command, write this password to a .txt file, then read this password on this text file and echo it.
If you didn't understand, here is my code. You can look at my code to understand it.

```bash
makepasswd=$(mkpasswd 12)
touch .pass
echo $makepasswd >> .pass
echo "$(<.pass)"
clear
read sifre
echo $sifre
```

Comment: is the saving required? your whole concept could be the 1st and last line storing the password into the sifre variable.

Comment: You don’t need `touch .pass` … the file will be created if it doesn’t exist by merely redirecting the output `>>` … and a simple `cat .pass` will display the content

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, it is required. I thinked about that too but then I remembered I have to save the password -_-

Comment: @Raffa Thank you for letting me know that I don't have to use touch. Secondly, I don't want to display content of a text file, I want to write the pass as a function.

Comment: Or `sifte=$(cat .pass)` if you need it in a variable.

Comment: @Raffa Thank you, solved my problem!

Comment: `"$(<.pass)"` is fine in bash, but won't work if you're executing the script with `sh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need `touch .pass` … the file will be created if it doesn’t exist by merely redirecting the output `>>` … and a simple `cat .pass` will display the content of the file ... or `sifre=$(cat .pass)` if you need it in a variable ... also please get into the habbit of quoting variables when used in commands like `echo "$makepasswd" >> .pass` ... so your script would look like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

makepasswd=$(mkpasswd 12)
echo "$makepasswd" >> .pass
sifre=$(cat .pass)
clear
echo "$sifre"
```